# IOS UI Interface

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-interface

I am creating an universal app for the iPad and iPhone. I have a UITextField where I want the user to enter the name of a song or any sound media file found in their iTunes library. My question is NOT about querying the library; I know how to do that. My question is an interface question on how best to present this to the user.

I would like for them to be able to first pick from a list of play lists. Then display all the song files in that play list. They will then choose one of those songs. The name of the song will then be displayed in the UITextField. Of course...if the user already knows the name of the song they can enter it directly.

So what interface elements (UIPickLists, UITableViews, PopOver (for iPad)) would you used to best present this to the user?

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` for all of the lists. It seems that you already want to use a `UITextField` for the name, but I would probably use a `UISearchBar/UISearchController` to search and a `UILabel` for display.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS6+ I would encourage you to use `UICollectionView` where you could actually present your playlists in a grid layout, then after your user selects some playlist you could present it's content via `UITableView`. It all depends what information about your playlists and songs you have. `UICollectionView` is pretty similar to `UITableView` when it comes to delegate and dataSource.

Comment: I kind of like this idea. In the collection view cell I can display the name of the play list and the number of songs. When the user clicks on a cell, I can then update a table view with the songs in that play list. On an iPhone; of course; I would have to navigate to another view controller. But on an iPad, I may be able to put both the collection view and table view on the same controller.